# How to add new data into the solr server

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, solr

I am new to solr.

I have a solr server.
I want to add some new data in the server.

How to do this?
I know this is a simple question. I searched on Google and not found any appropriate result.

Please share some good link to learn new data into the solr server and update the existing data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is exciting data? If I excited search Google for "solr server" I get plenty of links. Exciting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling on "solr add document" give me a first usefull result:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages

You need to post XML messages to your Solr server. You could do this with a curl library in C# but maybe there are any good libraries which serve a API to communicatie with Solr just like PHP.

I found one with 5 secs of Googling: http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/

Comment: Actually I want to add data using HTTP request.
Means I have only URL 'http: //address/solr'

I want to add document in that.No data is there in the server.
First i have to add data and then retrieve data from there.

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Can you please share the step by step process.
I want to add new document via HTTP,I wrote query like this
Please tell it is OK or I am going wrong.
My query:
http://192.168.10.113:8080/solr/update/?commit=true%20-H%20%22Content-Type:%20text/xml%22%20--data-binary%20'%3Cadd%3E%3Cdoc%3E%3Cfield%20name=%22id%22%3E17%3C/field%3E%3C/doc%3E%3C/add%3E

Comment: hi kees Schepers

please reply to question
please help.

Comment: You can add a document thru HTTP with curl for example like I said before. I don't get what you are asking. What you write is a URL not a query. You have to post a XML document to the URL you wrtie here above. To test you could do something like: curl http://192.168.10.113:8080/solr/update/?commitWithin=10000 -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary '<add><doc><field name="id">testdoc</field></doc></add>'

Comment: Thanks for reply

i want to add a document via ajax call in client side.
If i write -- curl http:// 192.168.10.113:8080/solr/update/?commitWithin=10000 -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary '<add><doc><field name="id">testdoc</field></doc></add>' -- in the url if the ajax then it will work ???

Comment: If I was you I would follow a course on programming cause guessing that you should put that in the url tells that you have very small knowledge or experience with development. The curl is a command for linux for example. You can't do a ajax request on Solr to add a document you need to write something your own in .net. Solr provides a rest interface.